# Fabric SDK Android Login

Tags: android

I read suggestion topics.

I want create social login in my application.

First of, I create blank `Activity With Fragment`. I added fb login its success running. Today I want add twitter login.

I read fabric documents and add `Fabric.Twitter-Kit`.

Problem is:

I click `Login With Twitter` button, it redirect twitter auth page "I confirm using API" not call success method.

I try again call failure method :).

**MainActivity Java**

```
package org.sckn.mobile;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "sosecret";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "sososecret";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}
}
```

MainAcitivtyFragment

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mtext;
     private EditText ed;
    TwitterLoginButton twlog;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> fbcallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken token =  loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if(profile!=null){
               // mtext.setText("Hi"+profile.getName());
                ed.setText(profile.getName());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


             FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //mtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblhw);
        Profile p = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        twlog = (TwitterLoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_buttontw);
        twlog.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                ed.setText("Ok");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                ed.setText("Nok");
            }


            });




       // mtext.setText("Hi" + p.getName().toString());
        LoginButton login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        login.setFragment(this);
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager,fbcallback);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    twlog.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    }


}
```

Where is my Issue?

Comment: try to move these lines to Application class TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

Comment: checkout this link for fabric implementation: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com